# Webpack bundled all files from dir

Tags: javascript, webpack

I bundled project with webpack 1. Project is consist of several folders. I noticed that js file that did not imported anywhere also end up in the bundle. Why does it happened?

As i know Webpack should resolve dependency graph and bundle file regarding it.But it seems it just bundle all files from the project directory.

Here is a part of my config:

```
  entry: {
    app: [path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/main.js')]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
    filename: '[name].[hash].js',
    publicPath: '/',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the empty string from resolve extension.

I prefer to use the loaders module like so:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0', 'es2015-ie'],
                plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-class-properties', 'transform-decorators-legacy'],
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.json$/,
            loader: 'json-loader'
        }
    ]
},
```

Comment: I import React without .js extension. So removing empty string let to ERROR.